# what are the best books for the IIT-JAM biological sciences exam?

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm from India and i'm preparing for a competitive exam called the Joint Admissions Test for a Masters admission.

I need help in finding books to read from for these chapters:

**General Biology**: Taxonomy and physiology, Pro-and eukaryotic organism; cell organelles and their function; multicellular Organization; energy transformations; internal transport systems of plants; respiration; regulation of body fluids and excretory mechanisms; cellular reproduction; Mendelian genetics and heredity; biology and populations and communities; evolution; genesis and diversity of organism; animal behaviour, plant and animal diseases.

**Basics of Biochemistry, Biophysics, Molecular Biology**: Buffers; trace elements in biological systems; enzymes and proteins; vitamins; biological oxidations, carbohydrates and lipids and their metabolisms; digestion and absorption; detoxifying mechanisms; plant and animal hormones and their action, nervous system, nucleic acids, nature of gene and its function, Genetic code, synthesis of nucleic acids and proteins. Enzyme mechanisms and kinetics, nucleic acid metabolism, photo synthesis.

**Structure of Biomolecules**: intra and intermolecular forces; thermodynamics and kinetics of biological systems, principles of x-ray diffraction, IR and UV spectroscopy and hydrodynamic techniques.

**Microbiology, Cell Biology and Immunology**: Classes of micro-organisms and their characterization, nutrient requirement for growth; laboratory techniques in microbiology, pathogenic micro-organisms and disease; applied microbiology; viruses, Microbial genetics. Innate and adaptive immunity, antigen antibodies.Cell theory; Cell architecture; methods of cell fractionation; cell division; types of chromosome structure; biochemical genetics- inborn errors of metabolisms; viruses and fungi; principles of processes of development.

PS. I've studied biology only until high school.

Comment: This question is just too broad. Also, asking for examination tips is tantamount to [homework](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). [Book recommendation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info) questions should be precise else they would be considered opinion-based. I'm sure there are plenty of websites that provide reading materials and recommend references for examinations like this. Unfortunately, this site is not one of them.